# Cannot install firebase CLI with npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I try to install `firebase-tools` with:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I get the following error:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
/usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/2609/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> protobufjs@6.8.9 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

2020/03/31 16:23:53.220338 cmd_run.go:884: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/nonexistent/snap/node/2609": mkdir /nonexistent: permission denied
cannot create user data directory: /nonexistent/snap/node/2609: Permission denied
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! protobufjs@6.8.9 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the protobufjs@6.8.9 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/david/.npm/_logs/2020-03-31T21_23_53_670Z-debug.log
```

I have googled this error but haven't found anything related. What can I do to install `firebase-tools`?

Comment: i am getting same issue while installing firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: You used used snap to install node and snap does not allows apps to write to `/usr/local` and this is where all the global packages are installed.

What you can do to fix this?

1. `snap remove node` - uninstall the snap version of node
2. `sudo apt-get install nodejs` - install nodejs
3. `npm install -g firebase-tools` - this should work now

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but i fixed it by not installing it globally

try this 
npm install firebase-tools

or

sudo npm install -g firebase-tools

Comment: Make sure and do that in the root project folder